# Iterate dataArray to create an object is not happening

Tags: node.js, reactjs, express

How can I parse the incoming `nomData` data array and store those values into an object along with userEmail ? Somehow below code is not working, could someone pleas advise the issue here.

Expected database columns values:

```
var data = { useremail: userEmail, nomineeemail: email, nomineename: name, nomineeteam: team, reason: reason }
```

`server.js`

```
    app.post('/service/nominateperson', async (req, res) => {
        try {
            const userEmail = req.body.userEmail;
            const nomData = req.body.nomRegister;
            const formData = {
                useremail: userEmail,
                nomineeemail: {},
                nomineename: {},
                nomineeteam: {},
                reason: {}
            }
            const newArray = nomData.map(item => {
                formData.nomineeemail = item.email;
                formData.nomineename = item.name;
                formData.nomineeteam = item.team;
                formData.reason = item.reason;
            });
var data = { useremail: userEmail, nomineeemail: email, nomineename: name, nomineeteam: team, reason: reason } 
           // Ideally I should get nomData 
           //items parsed create an data object and pass that into bulkCreat() method: 
            const numberOfNominations = await NominationModel.count({where: {useremail: userEmail}});
            if (numberOfNominations <= 3) {
                const nominationData = await NominationModel.bulkCreate(data);
                res.status(200).json({message: "Nomination submitted successfully !"});
            } else {
                res.status(202).json({message: "Nomination limit exceeded, please try next week !"});
            }
    
        } catch (e) {
            res.status(500).json({fail: e.message});
        }
    });
```

[image]

Comment: Can you specify what exactly isn't working? What is the expected result and what's the current result?

Comment: After iterating unable to get the ``nomData`` and userEmail into data..so that i can pass into  ``await NominationModel.bulkCreate(data);```method....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So i assume `nomData` is an array containing multiple nominations. So if you  want to `bulkCreate` with `data` you should pass an **array** instead of an object.

```
const data = nomData.map(item => ({
    useremail: userEmail,
    nomineeemail: item.email,
    nomineename: item.name,
    nomineeteam: item.team,
    reason: item.reason
}));
...
await NominationModel.bulkCreate(data)
```

Comment: Yes  ``nomData `` is an array contains multiple nominations ...But throws unexpected error at ``nomineeemail: item.email,```and others...

Comment: Will add the screen shot into the question

Comment: I have added the screen shot to the question

Comment: Some Parenthesis were missing. I edited my answer